# Redirect all .php pages to .htm in web.config

Tags: redirect, web-config

I wants to redirect all `.php` pages to `.htm` in **web.config**.

Please help me.

Note: Website running on IIS Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this web.config code, edit example.com with to your domain name

```
<rule name="rule 1C" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/http://www.example.com/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2C">
    <match url="^(.*).html$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```